# Unable to access AWS CodeCommit despite of having AWSCodeCommitFullAccess policy assigned

Tags: aws-codecommit, amazon-iam

My admin has assigned me managed `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess` policy but I am still unable to access CodeCommit service and when I expand the policy under user
I see following message:
[image]

The policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CloudWatchEventsCodeCommitRulesAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:DeleteRule",
                "events:DescribeRule",
                "events:DisableRule",
                "events:EnableRule",
                "events:PutRule",
                "events:PutTargets",
                "events:RemoveTargets",
                "events:ListTargetsByRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/codecommit*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SNSTopicAndSubscriptionAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:CreateTopic",
                "sns:DeleteTopic",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe",
                "sns:SetTopicAttributes"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:codecommit*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SNSTopicAndSubscriptionReadAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:GetTopicAttributes"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaReadOnlyListAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:ListFunctions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMReadOnlyListAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMReadOnlyConsoleAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMUserSSHKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMSelfManageServiceSpecificCredentials",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:UpdateServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:DeleteServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:ResetServiceSpecificCredential"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the policy , as it has all the parameters required ( Effect, Action and Resource ). And the this note does not make and sense :

> This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not
>   provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action
>   that has an applicable resource or condition

Answer (score 0):

Would you please provide what error message you have when you access CodeCommit service? Do you use AWS CLI to access CodeCommit? And do you use the correct security credentials(AccessKey and secret key)? The following documentation is how to setup HTTPS Connections to AWS CodeCommit Repositories, which might be helpful

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html#setting-up-https-unixes-account

Thanks

Comment: I am using Amazon Web Console not cli